# Getting average from a column sql

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query and wondering how i can implement a sum into this to calculate an average.

I have created this query to output the image below:

```
SELECT d.date, CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname) AS "Patient", dc.drugcost_cost, pc.pharmacy_name FROM drugcost dc JOIN patients_copy p ON dc.Patients_copy_idPatients = p.idPatients LEFT JOIN time d ON dc.time_idtime = d.idtime LEFT JOIN pharmacy_location pc ON dc.pharmacy_location_idpharmacy = pc.idpharmacy ORDER BY Patient ASC
```

[image]

I want to extend the query to get the average per year for the same patient in a new column or in a new query.

Is this possible? I hope you understand what i want.

Thanks

Comment: What about [avg](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp) function ?

Comment: What pharmacy name do you want to display when a user buys from two different ones?  Should those be concat_WS as well, a random one? or separate rows with different averages? ...

Comment: Well yes, i need the average of when 1 patient goes to 1 pharmacy, if it is another pharmacy name, the average should relate to that pharmacy, i hope u understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS "Year",
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname) AS "Patient", 
       AVG(dc.drugcost_cost) AS "AvgCost"
FROM drugcost dc 
     JOIN patients_copy p ON dc.Patients_copy_idPatients = p.idPatients 
     LEFT JOIN time d ON dc.time_idtime = d.idtime 
     LEFT JOIN pharmacy_location pc ON dc.pharmacy_location_idpharmacy = pc.idpharmacy 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
         ONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname)
```

To add pc.pharmacy_name  to the result:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS "Year",
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname) AS "Patient", 
       AVG(dc.drugcost_cost) AS "AvgCost",
       pc.pharmacy_name
FROM drugcost dc 
     JOIN patients_copy p ON dc.Patients_copy_idPatients = p.idPatients 
     LEFT JOIN time d ON dc.time_idtime = d.idtime 
     LEFT JOIN pharmacy_location pc ON dc.pharmacy_location_idpharmacy = pc.idpharmacy 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
         ONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname),
         pc.pharmacy_name
```

Comment: Ugh.. Use date functions to extract parts of dates. not string functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract or in this case `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)`

Comment: This is good but is it possible to get the average of the cost spent at a particular pharmacy so if they go to multiple pharmacies say Roger spends 5.99 and 6.99 in lloyds but also spends 2.99 and 4.99 in Harveys. so it gets the average of lloyds and harveys seperaely, i hope u understand.

Comment: Yes, just add <pc.pharmacy_name> into the select and group by

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, so i just add a round to round it up.

Comment: Yes so the AvgCost line would be ROUND(AVG(dc.drugcost_cost), {insert decimal places})

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` SQL function should help you

```
SELECT d.date, CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname) AS "Patient",  
       AVG(dc.drugcost_cost) AS "Average", pc.pharmacy_name 
FROM drugcost dc 
JOIN patients_copy p 
  ON dc.Patients_copy_idPatients = p.idPatients 
LEFT JOIN time d 
  ON dc.time_idtime = d.idtime 
LEFT JOIN pharmacy_location pc 
  ON dc.pharmacy_location_idpharmacy = pc.idpharmacy 
ORDER BY Patient ASC
```

```
SELECT d.date, CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname) AS "Patient",  
       AVG(dc.drugcost_cost) AS "Average", pc.pharmacy_name 
FROM drugcost dc 
JOIN patients_copy p 
  ON dc.Patients_copy_idPatients = p.idPatients 
LEFT JOIN time d 
  ON dc.time_idtime = d.idtime 
LEFT JOIN pharmacy_location pc 
  ON dc.pharmacy_location_idpharmacy = pc.idpharmacy 
GROUP BY "Patient"
ORDER BY Patient ASC
```

Comment: would likely need a group by for this to work correctly.

Comment: This only outputs one patient, how do i get all the patients?

Comment: you need to add GROUP BY `extract(YEAR FROM d.date), CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLname),  pc.pharmacy_name`

Comment: okay so i changed the order by to group by how do i get it to 2 decimals

Comment: @xQbert You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY extract(YEAR FROM d.date), CONCAT_WS(' ', p.PatientFname ,p.PatientLnam' at line 1

Comment: the simple way is to take AVG(DC.drugCost_Cost * 1.00)

Comment: No he's need to get annual average cost of drugs, groued by patient

Comment: @MarkZucchini FROM original Post, "I want to extend the query to get the average per year **for the same patient** in a new column or in a new query."

Comment: This is good but is it possible to get the average of the cost spent at a particular pharmacy so if they go to multiple pharmacies say Roger spends 5.99 and 6.99 in lloyds but also spends 2.99 and 4.99 in Harveys. so it gets the average of lloyds and harveys seperaely, i hope u understand.

Comment: Yes. AVG() and GROUP BY Patient

Comment: Ohm no, no. I was deceived by picture in question. You need use temporary table. And then execute the query I posted above